# The method setPriority (int) is undefined for the type Notification

Tags: android, notifications

Since Jelly Bean it is possible to set a priority to notifications. This way you can even set PRIORITY_MIN which will hide the notification icon on status bar.
I read about it and it is very simple, you just have to use this:

```
MyNotification.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MIN);
```

My problem es that I get the compile error:
**"The method setPriority (int) is undefined for the type Notification"**

My application has to run in different versions of Android, so, I understand that function is not available under JellyBean, so is there a way to include compiler tags or something similar to add that functionality depending on the Android release.
I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html] It simplifies things.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Android will handle this automagically. No need for additional markup for specific version numbers. When it comes to your compile error, I've had luck with something like my code below. You want to make sure to use `NotificationCompat` and make sure you import `android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;` as well.

### This code should work:

```
int pri = 0;
NotificationCompat.Builder MyNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx);
MyNotification.setPriority(pri);
```

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But Sorry, I get another compile error: "NotificationCompat cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: Make sure that you add this to your activity `import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;`

Comment: Now I get the error "The import android.support cannot be resolved" :-(

Comment: Make sure you have the support library included. Right click on the project file and go down to `Android Tools -> Add Support Library`

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add a little improvement **@EGHDK**'s answer.

## This is nice code:

```
int pri = 0;
NotificationCompat.Builder MyNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx);
MyNotification.setPriority(pri);
```

## With Little Improvement:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder MyNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx);
MyNotification.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT); // or any priority
```

less Error-Prone approach. Because i was using `Notification.PRIORITY_DEFAULT` and it **must** be `NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT`

> Anything that can go wrong will go wrong

[Murphy's law](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Murphy%27s_law)

Answer (score -1):

It is not working more than 26 android API
so check condition:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
val notificationBuilder:Notification.Builder=Notification.Builder(this,CHANNEL_Id)
                .setContentText("Big Text Notification")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .setLargeIcon(ic)
                .setStyle(bigTextNotification)
                .setContentText("this is Big Text Notification..")
            
}
else{
         .setContentText(" big text")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .setLargeIcon(ic)
                .setStyle(bigText)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
       
}
```

You can use `NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT`