# Android : Manage place of one notification among multiple Notifications

Tags: android, notifications

I am working in application that contain lost of push notifications, in each push notification , i have to put play icon to play the music of each notification. problem when i am updating the notification means play to pause or pause to play. than notification update but the notification goes on the top each time.

I want to know , **is there way to stay notification on there place after notification update ?**

I show some image, to explain briefly.

[image]

[image]

Please help me thanks in advance.

Comment: it just blinking issue.I found Solution and answered here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28021665/android-multiple-notification-avoid-blinking-while-updating

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setpriority to set the priority of the notification..

Check this post for more info

[The method setPriority (int) is undefined for the type Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13808939/jelly-bean-the-method-setpriorityint-is-undefined-for-the-type-notification)